# Media recommendation engine - Single user system - How to start

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, recommendation-engine, collective-intelligence, embedded

I want to implement a media recommendation engine. I saw a similar posts on this, but I think my requirements are bit different from those, so posting here.

Here is the deal.

I want to implement a recommendation engine for media players like VLC, which would be an engine that has to care for only single user. Like, it would be embedded in a media player on a PC which is typically used by **single user**. And it will start learning the likes and dislikes of the user and gradually learns what a user likes. **Here it will not be able to find similar users for using their data for recommendation as its a single user system**. So how to go about this?

**Or you can consider it as a recommendation engine that has to be put in say iPods, which has to learn about a single user and recommend music/Movies from the collections it has.**

I thought of start collecting the genre of music/movies (maybe even artist name) that user watches and recommend movies from the most watched Genre, but it look very crude, isn't it?

So is there any algorithms I can use or any resources I can refer up to?

Regards,

MicroKernel :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're trying to do is quite challenging... particularly because it's still in the research stage and a lot of PHDs from reputable universities across the world are trying to get a good solution for that.

SO here are some things that you might need:

1. Data that you can analyze:

   - Lots, and lots, and lots of data!
   - It could be meta data about the media (name, duration, title, author, style, etc.)
   - Or you can try to do some crazy feature extraction from the media itself.
2. References to correlate the data to.

   - Since you can't get other users, you always need the user feedback.
   - If you don't want to annoy your user to death with feedback questions, then make your application connect to a central server so you can compare users.
3. An algorithm that can model your data sufficiently well.

   - If you have no experience at all, then try [k-nearest neighbor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbor_algorithm) (the simplest one).
   - [Collaborative filtering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collaborative_filtering)
   - [Pearson Correlation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation)
   - [Matrix Factorization/Decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_factorization)
   - [Singular value decomposition (SVD)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_approximation)
   - [Ensemble learning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ensemble_learning) <-- Allows you to combine multiple algorithms and take advantage of their strengths.

The winners of the NetFlix prize said this:

> Predictive accuracy is substantially
>   improved when blending multiple
>   predictors. Our experience is that
>   most efforts should be concentrated in
>   deriving substantially different
>   approaches, rather than refining a
>   single technique. Consequently, our
>   solution is an ensemble of many
>   methods.

### Conclusion:

There is no silver bullet for recommendation engines and it takes years of exploration to find a good combination of algorithms that produce sufficient results. :)

Comment: @Microkernel, well... let's just say it's not *exactly* an easy thing to do.